If i have an arc that I have split by a point, how can I get the angles of the new 2 arcs?
I have a arc that can be defined by a known radius and an arc angle. If the start of the arc and the end of the arc are both defined in $x$ and $y$ axis by known points...
Then my question is, if I decided to divide that arc into 2 arcs not equally by selecting a point on the x axis without knowing the y axis, where the arcs will be separated? How can I use the known information to get each angle for each arc with the least steps?

yes i can determine the right center point using the information that i have, but what should i do after this to insure a solution with least possible steps?

@trula yes i can determine it

you have the equation of the circle $x=x_m+rcos(t+\phi),y=y_m+rsin(t+\phi)$ find  by putting in one of your known points, than the x,y coordinate of your first known point $(x_1,y_1)$ to find $\phi$ and following the x coordinate of the new point. to determine the angle relative to $(x_1,y_1)$
